# How do I delete a row in a join table automatically, to avoid a ConstraintViolationException?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpql

This seems like it should be a pretty simple question, or at least have a simple answer. But -  I'm really not a database guy, and I'm still pretty far down on the Hibernate learning curve. That said, here's the setup:

Consider a unidirectional many-to-many relationship between two entities, from `Foo` to `Bar`:

<sup>(pardon any typos below, the following is obviously a simplification of the actual code)</sup>

#### FooDTO.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyDB.dbo.Foo")
class FooDTO implements Serializable
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<BarDTO> bars = new HashSet<BarDTO>();

    ...

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "MyDB.dbo.FooBar",
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fooId") },
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "barId") })
    public Set<BarDTO> getBars()
    {
        return bars;
    }
    public void setBars(Set<Bar> bars)
    {
        this.bars = bars;
    }
}
```

#### BarDTO.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyDB.dbo.Bar")
class BarDTO implements Serializable
{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

On the TSQL side, the join table is set up like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FooBar](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [fooId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [barId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_FooBar_FooId FOREIGN KEY (fooId) REFERENCES [dbo].[Foo](id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_FooBar_BarId FOREIGN KEY (barId) REFERENCES [dbo].[Bar](id),
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
```

If I try to outright delete a `BarDTO`, I get a `ConstraintViolationException` because I haven't first deleted the row in the join table (duh).

#### Questions:

- Can I get Hibernate to drop the rows in the join table automagically, when I delete a `Bar`? How?
- If not, how do I select all the `Foo`s that have a particular `Bar`, so I can remove that `Bar` from each relevant `Foo`'s set of `Bar`s?

With regard to the latter question, I *think* this could be done with either a `NamedQuery` or using the Criteria API, but I don't know specifically how to write such a query or which constraints to apply. I think it would a named query would look something like:

```
SELECT f FROM FooDTO f INNER JOIN ??? WHERE f.id = ???
```

but I'm not sure where the `barId` parameter would go, or how to join on the `FooBar` table since I don't declare it as an entity. (Side note, I also recall previous issues with trying to join in a named query - is joining in a named query impossible?)

Comment: does BarDTO have get/setFoos defined?

Comment: @Mikeb - no, it doesn't. Hence the unidirectional relationship.

Comment: I think its either that, or a missing Cascade annotation.

Comment: @Mikeb - someone else already posted an answer about cascading, and then deleted it after I commented. Basically - cascading isn't the answer, since my question isn't about deleting all of a `Foo`'s `Bar`s when deleting a `Foo`. I'm just trying to automatically dissociate a `Bar` from all of the `Foo`s that care about it, so I can delete the `Bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I get Hibernate to drop the rows in the join table automagically, when I delete a Bar? How?

You need to remove the `BarDTO` instance from the collections in `FooDTO` that holds a reference on it.

> If not, how do I select all the Foos that have a particular Bar, so I can remove that Bar from each relevant Foo's set of Bars?

The following should work:

```
SELECT f FROM FooDTO f WHERE :bar MEMBER OF f.bars
```

Or you could make the association bidirectional and simply call `bar.getFoos()`.

Comment: Would that HQL go in a NamedQuery? E.g., `@NamedQuery(name = "FooDTO.findByBar", query = "SELECT r FROM FooDTO f WHERE :bar MEMBER f.bars")` ? Or would it have to be written as `entityManager.createQuery(...)`?

Comment: @Bears It's as you want, there is nothing preventing this query to be used as a named query.