# Hibernate/jpa many-to-many

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm having 2 tables Pizza and toppings,

```
   class pizza{
...
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = com.pizzastudyds.db.bean.Topping.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "PIZZATOPPING", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PIZZAID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TOPPINGID"))
        public Set<Topping> getToppings() {
            return toppings;
        }
...
    } 

class toppings{
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "toppings", targetEntity = com.pizzastudyds.db.bean.Pizza.class)
    public Set<Pizza> getPizzas() {
        return pizzas;
    }
}
```

This 2 classes have many to many relation ship , when I define toppings for an pizza. Then try to delete the pizza I'm able to do so but when I'm deleting the topping object and if there is a relationship between tooping and pizza. then I'm not able to delete the topping and get the exception of constraint viloation.

I want to delete both pizza & topping separately irrespective of relationship i.e; I want to update the join table as well as delete from both sides. How can I do that?

Actually what I want is to delete pizza and topping separately i.e; Like if I delete pizza it get deleted and updates the join table similarly when I delete the topping it get deleted updating the relationship in join table. I don't mean that if I delete topping, pizza get deleted or vice-vesra.

Comment: You need to manually remove all of the topping's pizzas before deleting a topping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a row in a join table automatically, to avoid a ConstraintViolationException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719814/how-do-i-delete-a-row-in-a-join-table-automatically-to-avoid-a-constraintviolat)

Comment: Btw: you can omit the annotation value @ManyToMany.targetEntity because this is exact the default (determined by the generics from the set)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
```

Add this on both sides. I hope this will solve your problem.